# How to retrieve data from Sql Server database?

Tags: java, android, uitableview, android-tablelayout

I am new to Android. I am already connected to the SQL Server and I want to retrieve data from the database and show it in a Table.

**Here is the code:**

```
public  void QuerySQL(String COMANDOSQL) {

    try {
        //String sql="select * from Activity";
        Statement stmt = ma.connect.createStatement();


        stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM "+excbtn.getText().toString()+"");
        ResultSet rs=stmt.getResultSet();
        ResultSetMetaData rsmd= rs.getMetaData();
        int colcount=rsmd.getColumnCount();
        int j=0;

        while(rs.next()){
            j++;
            for(int i=1; i<=colcount; i++)
            {
                String ss=rsmd.getColumnName(i);
                // create a new TextView

                if(j<=colcount){
                t = new TextView(this);
                t.setText(ss);
                t.setWidth(200);//Set to any meaningful text
                t.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
                tr.addView(t); //Attach TextView to its parent (row)
                TableRow.LayoutParams params =
                        (TableRow.LayoutParams)t.getLayoutParams();
                params.column= i; //place at ith columns.

                params.span = 1; //span these many columns,

                params.setMargins(2,2,2,2);

                params.width = TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT;

                params.height = TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
                t.setPadding(2, 2, 2, 2);

                t.setLayoutParams(params);

                    //colhead=true;
               }


                    t1 = new TextView(this);
                    String tabval=rs.getString(ss);
                    t1.setText(rs.getString(ss));
                    t1.setWidth(200);//Set to any meaningful text
                   // t1.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
                    tr1.addView(t1); //Attach TextView to its parent (row)
                    TableRow.LayoutParams params1 =
                            (TableRow.LayoutParams)t.getLayoutParams();
                    params1.column= i; //place at ith columns.

                    params1.span = j; //span these many columns,

                    params1.setMargins(2,2,2,2);

                    params1.width = TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT;

                    params1.height = TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
                    t1.setPadding(2, 2, 2, 2);
                    t1.setLayoutParams(params1);

                    //String from = {ss1};


                }
```

How to bind the data and where to execute table row?

Comment: is your data is on remote server or local to device?

Comment: using remote server..

Comment: **using remote server** @dd619

Comment: i think you need webservice to get data from sqlite server

Answer (score 1):

By assuming your database on remote server-

1)You need a WebService to retrieve data from the server.

2)After retrieving the data from server you need parse it using its format e.g JSON,XML

3)After parsing the data you can manipulate or store it as per your application need.

(right now,focus on how to retrieve data from server using WebService, once you have data,focus on your UI part )